# $\int_{x}^{1} e^{t^3} \,dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Can someone give me  hint for solving

$$\int_{x}^{1} e^{t^3} \,dt $$

$$$$

Actually I met 
$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{y}^{1}  \int_{x}^{1}  e^{t^3} \,dt  \,dx  \,dy. $$

How can I evaluate this integral?

Thanks a lot.

### $$$$

$$$$

Wolfram doesn't show the result  [enter link description here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E1%20int_y%5E1%20int_z%5E1%20e%5E(t%5E3)%20%20dt%20dx%20dy)

To. **Lord Shark the Unknown**

You mean

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t}  \int_{y}^{1}  e^{t^3} \,dx  \,dy  \,dt $$.
??

(Because $0<y<x<t<1$)

Comment: You don't do the second by doing the first! rather you change the order of integration in the second.

Comment: I do not think there is a closed form for that....

Comment: @dmtri: there clearly is.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think dmtri meant for the single integral...

Comment: WA says this here $$\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{x \left(\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3},-x^3\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\right)}{\sqrt[3]{-x^3}}+(-1
   )^{2/3} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3},-1\right)-3
   \Gamma \left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: very irrelevant, as usual.

Comment: Thank you for your nice comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong way to go. $\int_{x}^{1}e^{t^3}\,dt$, just like $\int_{0}^{a}e^{-x^2}\,dx$, is not an elementary function.
On the other hand by Cavalieri's principle
$$ \iiint_{0\leq y\leq x\leq t\leq 1}e^{t^3}\,dt\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^2}{2}e^{t^3}\,dt=\left[\frac{1}{6}e^{t^3}\right]_{0}^{1}=\color{red}{\frac{e-1}{6}}. $$

Comment: How can I get $\frac{t^2}{ 2 } $ (on the 2nd part)?

Comment: Please elaborate on how you rigorously applied Cavalieri’s principle.

Comment: @Szeto: for any $t\in(0,1)$,  $\frac{t^2}{2}$ is the Lebesgue measure of $\{(x,y):0\leq y\leq x\leq t\}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Ah... I should have digested 'Lebesgue measure'... Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the order like this

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t}  \int_{0}^{x}  e^{t^3} \,dy  \,dx  \,dt $$
$$ = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{t}   xe^{t^3} \,dx  \,dt $$
$$ = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{t^2}{2}e^{t^3} \,dt $$

But I am still curious about @Jack D'Aurizio

How can I apply Cavalieri's principle for evaluating this triple integration.

Comment: It's exactly what you have done by changing the order of integration. See my comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the expansion of $e^x$
$$\int_x^1 e^{t^3}\ dt = \int_x^1 \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{t^{3n}}{n!}\ dt= \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{1-x^{3n+1}}{n!(3n+1)}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help.